# Join on ((= Statement) or ((!= Statement), other stipulations))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some information where the IdNumbers (not primary key Ids, just random Ids assigned to individuals) are not always correct in my first table.

Therefore I am joining my second table on both Ids and names, and trying to get it to where it will join on names only if the IdNumbers do not match.

I'm working on a query with a join statement that is roughly as follows (I'm leaving out the SELECT, WHERE, and ORDER BY sections because I believe that they are not having an effect on this issue and I don't want to be confusing, as they are stupidly complex - if the portion of the query below should be working like I want it to and the problem is obviously somewhere else, then just tell me so and that will answer my question):

```
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON ((Table1.IdNumber = Table2.IdNumber) 
OR (Table1.IdNumber != Table2.IdNumber 
    AND Table1.Lname = Table2.Lname 
    AND Table1.Fname = Table2.Fname))
```

However, it is joining the people who have both matching Ids and matching names multiple times like so:

```
Fname   M   Lname   Table1.IdNumber  Table2.IdNumber2
Matthew -   Smith   1                2
Matthew H   Smith   2                1
Matthew -   Smith   1                1
Matthew H   Smith   2                2
```

So it is pulling the last 2 because their ids match, but also joining the first 2 because their ids do not match and their names match, but why is it even joining the first 2 to begin with? I suspect that it ignores the != statement when deciding where to join since the other conditions are fulfilled, but I'd like it to take this != statement into account somehow.

If this should be working, like I said before, just tell me and it will answer my question.

(*EDIT)
Sorry, I should have named these properly - I've revised the names. And the full outer join is necessary, I need everything from both tables no matter what and it's working fine, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please show which columns belong to which table. BTW: Are you sure you want a FULL OUTER JOIN and not an INNER JOIN?

Comment: In your example those all appear to be unique records.  Can you provide us with a fiddle?

Comment: It IS taking the `!=` into account - in the first row of your results, `1!=2`.  You need some kind of `NOT EXISTS` a matching row by ID, but unfortunately this will be much more complex than your current `JOIN`.

Comment: @cjk I updated with better column names (I totally botched it at first) but I am worried that you may be correct, I was hoping it would filter for != before jumping in and matching names.

Comment: @JackArbiter . . . It is joining on both equal ids and on equal names.  Are you trying to get the logic "join on ids if the same, otherwise join on names".  Can you provide sample output?  I'm not clear what you are trying to get.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do exactly what you said. The sample output would just be the bottom two rows since it would detect that they have matching ids and wouldn't also match them for names. Right now I'm trying Woot4Moo's suggested answer and I may be on to something, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how messy this would be to do in one JOIN, I would suggest using a temp table to hold the relationships.

You can insert all of your IDs from the into first table into a temp table, then do two passes to update a column holding the 2nd table ID - first using where the ID matches, and second where the ID doesn't match but the name does.

You can then use this table to join the two tables, retrieving up to one record from table 2 for each record in table 1.

Comment: Thanks, you convinced me not to try this using joins and put me on the right track as far as temp tables. I used something similar to your suggestion: DELETE FROM table2
WHERE EXISTS
  ( select IdNumber
    from table1
    where table1.IdNumber = table2.Idnumber) and with a few more steps got what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.*,t2.*  
from t1,t2  
where  t1.id = t2.id  
and  t1.name = t2.name
union  
select t1.*,t2.*  
from t1,t2  
where  t1.id ! t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work, if the columns are coming from the right tables.  Because you are not using table aliases, I suspect that you have an expression such as:

```
fname1 = fname2
```

and both columns are in the same table.  Or worse:

```
fname1 = fname1
```

which is essentially always TRUE (except when fname1 is not null).

Your query might work, but it will be inefficient in most databases, because they will use nested loop optimizations.  Consider rewriting the query to be:

```
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 byID
     on t1.IdNumber = byID.IdNumber full outer join
     table2 byName
     on t1.fname = byName.fname and t1.lname = byName.lname and t1.idNumber <> byName.idNumber
```

This will require changing other clauses in your query, typically to something like:

```
coalesce(byId.column, byName.column) as Column
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've botched the names (and I've since revised them), I meant to show they were coming from table 1 and table 2 but of course that's not at all what I put in the question at first :)